# Book about mankind entering the space age and their first contact with two civilizations in sol

Tags: story-identification

There was a book I read 28 years ago. Remembering it was a good read I just want to re-read it, but I don't remember its name.

The synopsis is (as I remember):

> Mankind is about to go to the Moon for the first time, and after they get there they find traces of civilization, with still-working machines. They find a lot of clues which lead them to think that aliens who lived there are still located on the Mars. They build one communication device and try to communicate with aliens on Mars, and they respond. With plans given from Mars they build some stronger rocket, and the main protagonist flies to Mars also. He finds there that the "aliens" look just like common people, although they are taller a bit.
>
> And there was also a third species in the solar system, I think on Ganymede. They were 20 feet tall, called themselves "Lothar" or something similar. They had some kind of taboo about flying to the inner part of the solar system, so they never actually made real contact with Mars people, although they were at war. They live in globe-shaped houses that levitate.
>
> There is a mention that war between two races was ended by destroying the planet between Mars and Jupiter, where now an asteroid belt can be found.
>
> They mention a fourth civilization also, but nobody knows anything about them, except that their technology is superior.

I tried to search for it on the internet, but I can't seem to find any information about it.

I'm not sure that the story I wrote above is 100% accurate, I was a child then. I remember the book was very thick, having lots of pages.

Does anybody know what the title is and who is the writer?

Comment: Some of the details remind me of a James P.Hogan story. Possibly Inherit the Stars.

Comment: Its not the book I'm looking for, but surely I will read this one also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm almost 100% sure that the writer is Manfred Langrenus, and the book is Reich im Mond (Empire on Moon), just need some time to go to the local library and check if I'm right.

*Update*:

This is the book I was searching for. Although it have really unattractive name, the content compensate you with rich and remarkable story. If you can, read it. You won't regret.

Comment: This book only seems to be in German and a translation to Croatian.