# Are there English translations of works of Manfred Langrenus?

Tags: story-identification, translation

Does anybody know of any English translations of Manfred Langrenus's books?
I have read *Empire on the Moon* (subject of [this story-identification question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85145/book-about-mankind-entering-the-space-age-and-their-first-contact-with-two-civil)) translated into Croatian a long time ago, now I would like to find the translation of the sequel *Im Banne des Alpha Centauri*, preferably in English.
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi) does not show any  translations of [*Reich im Mond*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1519582) or [*Im Banne des Alpha Centauri*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1519583) by [Manfred Langrenus](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?181955) (pseudonym of [Friedrich Hecht](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Hecht)). This does not necessarily mean that no English translations exist; the ISFDB doesn't know everything.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the entries of [Reich im Mond](http://www.sf-leihbuch.de/static/buch1158.htm) and [Im Banne des Alpha Centauri](http://www.sf-leihbuch.de/static/buch1159.htm) at http://www.sf-leihbuch.de, the first one lists the translation into Croatian, while the second one list no translations at all.

I see this as a strong indication that there are no translations in English.

Comment: Yes... that was my conclusion also. Google translate is a pain...

Comment: Well, I will try translation into English from Google translation, when time permits, I think it will be worth it (at least for nostalgics like me...)